# What type of Mint is this?

Tags: identification, herbs, food-crops

Looking to ID the type of Mint this is, it is for my tortoise. I got it from my local grocery store, it's branded as Compliments Organic Mint.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called English mint & Spearmint (Mentha spicata).  This is a very good mint for cooking, fresh salads and used in various alcoholic drinks, like mojitos.

[Success with Mints](https://www.richters.com/show.cgi?page=MagazineRack/Articles/mint.html)
[Mints for Tortoises](https://www.thetortoisetable.org.uk/plant-database/viewplants/?plant=506#.XgUzAyHPyUk)